# Automatic read files with similar names

Tags: python

Sorry that I am a newbie in Python

How can I automatically read different files with similar names (only changing the numbers with increments), under the same folder ? For example I need to make an array out of this file cons.1.00, and I have other files which I want to make other arrays out of, such as cons.1.01, cons.1.02..... etc. Is there some functions or loops for me to accomplish this task ?

Here is my code for my attempt, but since I will have to do this for many files I was wondering if there is a better way to do it.

```
c0 = np.loadtxt(r'C:\Users\holde\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\cons.1.00.dat')
c1 = np.loadtxt(r'C:\Users\holde\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\cons.1.01.dat')
c2 = np.loadtxt(r'C:\Users\holde\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\cons.1.02.dat')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use glob package to get list of files with specific pattern:

```
import glob
import numpy as np

list_c = []

for x in glob.glob("C:\Users\holde\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\cons.1.*.dat"):
  c = np.loadtxt(x)
  list_c.append(c)
```

Or using list comprehension:

```
[ np.loadtxt(x) for x in glob.glob("C:\Users\holde\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\cons.1.*.dat") ]
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Note that this also work on Windows even if `glob` is often associated with unix:

> The glob module finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern according to the rules used by the Unix shell, although results are returned in arbitrary order. No tilde expansion is done, but *, ?, and character ranges expressed with [] will be correctly matched. This is done by using the os.scandir() and fnmatch.fnmatch() functions in concert, and not by actually invoking a subshell. Note that unlike fnmatch.fnmatch(), glob treats filenames beginning with a dot (.) as special cases. (For tilde and shell variable expansion, use os.path.expanduser() and os.path.expandvars().)

Answer (score 0):

Any time you're doing the same thing over and over and only one thing is changing, you want to use a loop:

```
c = [
    np.loadtxt(r'C:\Users\holde\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\' + f'cons.1.{i:02d}.dat')
    for i in range(3)
]
```